# Read packet counter from iptables for a specific rule

Tags: iptables

I have a box where forwarding rules are being created and deleted all the time using iptables. The box can have more than 5000 rules.

I want to read the packet counter for a specific rule using something like this:

```
iptables -v -C FORWARD -p udp -s 10.1.1.10 -j ACCEPT
```

But it does not output the counters. Only when doing it like this:

```
iptables -v -L FORWARD
```

do it show the counters, but now it show it for all 5000+ rules, which sounds like a waste of resources.

Is there no way to just lookup the counters for a single rule?

Comment: What resources could it possibly be wasting?  Try `iptables -L -n -v -x | grep ...`, and go from there.

Comment: @MadHatter I have a web interface where I show a realtime graph with the packet usage for a given rule, which requires me to fetch the counters once a second. Do you believe running `iptables -nvxL` once a second uses so little CPU and blocks iptables access (xtables lock) so briefly that I should not care about it?

Comment: Honestly?  I don't know.  But [the netfilter FAQ](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/FAQ/netfilter-faq-4.html#ss4.5) continues to confirm that there's no stable API into the kernel structures except for the `iptables` tools.  If you believe they **are** imposing a significant load, then you have to decide whether the business need to have these data on a 1s resolution (and I note you haven't told us what that need is) outweighs the cost of gathering it.